# Trying to create a simple shopping cart in PHP with sessions

Tags: php, session, cart

I've got an assignment where we're supposed to create an eCommerce website that pulls products from a database, lists them and allows you to add them to a cart, though only a single quantity of the item is required but it must have other functions as well, which I think I could figure out on my own.

What I'm trying to work on right now is actually adding items to my cart when the user clicks on the "Buy Now" button I've created for each item pulled from the database but I'm so bloody lost. I'm trying to use a session for the cart so everything is erased when the browser is closed.

Here's what I've got for the page that lists the items available:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    echo '<div id="description">';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<h2>'.$row['Name'].'</h2>';
            echo '<p>'.$row['Description'].'</p>';
            echo '<a href="cart.php" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="buyNow">Buy Now - $'.$row['Price'].'.00</a>';
        }
    }else{
        echo "There is something wrong.";
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

And here's what I've got for the cart:

```
<?php 

require('connection.php'); 
session_start();

$cart_content = array(); 

?>
```

I haven't gotten past creating the bones for the array that will be the cart items. I don't know if I'm having an off-morning or what, but I can't seem to figure out how to add items with the buttons I have created. When I think about doing it, it seems like it should be easy but I just can't figure it out, no matter the tutorials I look at. For now, this is the only thing I need help with because I'm pretty sure I can figure out the rest on my own.

Comment: Also parse the ID of the product in your while loop.  When the button add to cart is clicked, search your database using prepared statements and add the product to a session variable.  Then on checkout,  loop through that session variable and display the items with the prices. You can then build in PayPal gateway or another payment gateway

Answer (score 0):

First as you are using an anchor tag to launch the CART processing you need to add the `id` to the querystring

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // show all products in this script
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    echo '<div id="description">';
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            // stop it showing a product if it has already been selected by user
            if ( ! in_array($row['id'], $_SESSION['cart'] ) {
                echo '<h2>'.$row['Name'].'</h2>';
                echo '<p>'.$row['Description'].'</p>';
                echo '<a href="cart.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="buyNow">Buy Now - $'.$row['Price'].'.00</a>';
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "There is something wrong.";
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Now when you look for `$_GET['id']` in the cart processing script it should exist in `$_GET['id']`. All you need to do is add it to something in the `$_SESSION` array that you can later view. Its usful to give that array a sensible name in $_SESSION.

```
<?php 
session_start();
require('connection.php'); 

// add this id to the cart array in the session
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['id']; 
// re-run the first script
header('Location: xxxx.php');   // sorry dont know what the fist script is called

?>
```

Comment: I don't really understand the comment you added above the _SESSION variable. Should I keep the original $cart_content = array(); in addition to adding the $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_GET['id'];?

Comment: It should no be necessary

Comment: Okay, so I got my ID carrying over to the cart.php page and with a little bit of extra work I should be able to get the relevant data to show up as well, but I'm still not sure how I would be able to have the user click the "Buy Now" button on multiple items and have each item added to the cart.

Comment: Each time you click a BUY. it will run the `cart.php` script and add a new item to the array.

Comment: It doesn't seem to do that, I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do. I don't mean to be a pain, but would you mind explaining that again?

Comment: I changed the code a litttle. Now the first script get ALL the products. It also checks the SESSION['cart'] array to see if that product has been selected already, and does not show a product again if it was selected.

Comment: And made the cart.php scritp rerun the first script once it has been run.